# Get Axis перестаёт работать, после отработки столкновения c коллайдером

Tags: c#, unity3d

Снимаю данные для угла поворота функцией GetAxis:

```
    turnAngle = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speedRot* Time.deltaTime;
```

и далее в Update() работает функция MoveHorizont():

```
private void MoveHorizont()
{        
    Quaternion RotAngle = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, turnAngle);
    transform.Rotate(0, turnAngle, 0);
}
```

После того как вертолёт сталкивается с препятствием, само препятствие просто с Rigibody и коллайдером, без скриптов, перестаёт работать получение данных о горизонтальной оси. Анимации отрабатывают потому что привязаны непосредственно к кнопкам. Есть у кого идеи почему перестаёт работать Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") ?

По ссылке видео в котором показано как глючит поворот. Анимация работает, а реально поворот зациклен, как-будто постоянно нажата клавиша.

https://yadi.sk/i/bZtZ8G-iou-CSQ

Comment: Конкретно команда `Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")` не может перестать работать, это "внутренняя кухня" unity и из кода игры это не сломать. Чтобы убедиться в этом - сделайте `Debug.Log`. Так что проблема в чем-то другом.

Comment: Согласен, потому и добавил метку unity3d.Идея есть куда копать что смотреть? Почему оно работает без перебоев до столкновения в объектом на котором только коллайдер и компонент Rigibody, без скриптов?

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил. Ошибка была в коде.
У меня проверяется статус врезания вертолёта в разные объекты. Всё отрабатывало нормально, только функция краш() по которой останавливается всё попадала в область в которой работать не должна. В итоге она останавливала работу с переменными в том числе и поворота, а анимация продолжала работать как положено(потому что не обрабатывается после функции краш, так как заменяется сломанной моделью и падает на пол и дымится)
Спасибо всем кто пытался помочь.